# Combine already minified js files

Tags: minify, pagespeed

Is there a way to combine **ALREADY MINIFIED** JavaScript files into a single file?

When my page loads I get lots of queue time. How can I reduce that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends on the framework that you are using.

If you are using an ASP. NET application you could add all the javascript files to BundleConfig.cs and set `EnableOptimizations` as true.

Doing this would significantly reduce the load time.

Comment: Thank for the comment. I am using PHP here.